# click event on button prevented for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to modify the css properties of a div by triggering a click event. For some reason, this isn't happening and it's driving me crazy. Do you know why this happens?

The event looks like this:

```
$("#colButton3").on("click", function() {
    unCollapse('#CarouselSpace','#CarouselBody');
});
```

The unCollapse function is this:

```
var unCollapse = function(headerElement, bodyElement) {
    $(headerElement).css('margin-top', '1500px');
    $(bodyElement).css('min-height', '820px');
};
```

And the button itself is generated with jquery, but its html is:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" href="#" id="colButton3" style="display: inline-block;">Learn More</button>
```

The target divs are these:

```
<div id="CarouselSpace" class="row"><h1 id="CarouselHeader"></h1></div>
<div id="CarouselBody" class="row"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Is this an element that is loaded when the page is loaded, or does it get appended later on?

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/fm4d9jey/). Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Try to use `$("body").on("click","#colButton3",function() { //Your code });`

Comment: Actually, it's triggered by clicking the button. It's not supposed to happen when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic elements needs to have the bind on the document  not the element itself as the element is loaded after the document loads

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(document).on("click", "#colButton3", function() {
    unCollapse('#CarouselSpace', '#CarouselBody');
  });
});


var unCollapse = function(headerElement, bodyElement) {
  $(headerElement).css('margin-top', '1500px');
  $(bodyElement).css('min-height', '820px');
};
```

```css
#CarouselBody,
#CarouselSpace {
  border: 1px solid #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CarouselSpace" class="row">
  <h1 id="CarouselHeader">Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="CarouselBody" class="row">Body</div>
<button id=colButton3>button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should work, you are probably trying to bind click event before you create the button. Try using $.live or bind after creating the button.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm new at this. How come?

Comment: You have to insert this kind of answer in comment section of question.

Comment: How can i recognise if my anwser is "this kind"?

Comment: Is that solve the OP problem? Add more explanation to your answer, provide a demo and etc.

Comment: If by "solving problem" you understand writing the code for him, than no it didn't. 

When the question can be anwsered in one sentence why would i provide a demo for it? Maybe "should work" was unfortunate begining of the sentence, but i checked his code, and switched order of things and most probably thats the case - so why wouldn't i tell him that? And by my expirience i know that doing something by yourself teaches you more than copying the code from here :)

Don't want to get into discussion about is that approach correct or not, but i will sometimes give anwsers like that.